# »Fut« = »Gesäß«? Wo im deutschen Sprachraum?

Tags: meaning, regional

Mit dem Substantiv »Fut« bezeichnet man in Österreich auf sehr grob-abwertende Art das Geschlechtsorgan einer Frau. Es ist ein Wort aus der Gossen-Sprache, wird auch als grobes Schimpfwort benutzt, und ist eines der abwertendsten und schmutzigsten Worte, die ich kenne.

Nun trat aber vor wenigen Tagen die seit 25 Jahren in Österreich lebende, aber in Deutschland geborene Schauspielerin [Elke Winkens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elke_Winkens) in einer humorigen Talkshow in einem österreichischen Privatsender auf. Bei dieser Gelegenheit erzählte sie, dass ihr Spitzname, als sie noch ein Kind war und in Deutschland lebte,

> Entenfut

war. Auch ihr Vater nannte sie so, und rief sie - wie Frau Winkens erzählte - auch einmal bei einer in Österreich stattfindenden öffentlichen Veranstaltung, bei der sie auftrat, mit diesem Kosenamen, was unter den anwesenden Gästen für großes Befremden sorgte.

Frau Winkens ging in der Talkshow auf den Bestandteil »Ente« in ihrem Kosenamen nicht weiter ein, hob aber ausdrücklich hervor, dass das Wort »Fut« in der Gegend, wo sie aufgewachsen ist (ihre Familie lebt laut Wikipedia in [Hückelhoven](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckelhoven)), »Hinterteil« bzw. »Gesäß« bedeuten würde, und dass man dort nichts dabei fände dieses Wort auch in der Öffentlichkeit und offenbar auch in der Familie zu verwenden (immerhin wurde sie, als sie noch ein Kind war, von ihrem Vater so genannt).

Da auch [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fut) und [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fut) das Wort »Fut« nur als vulgäre Bezeichnung der Vulva kennen, interessiert mich nun, wo im deutschen Sprachraum das Wort »Fut« überhaupt bekannt ist, und was es dort jeweils für eine Bedeutung hat.

Comment: Naja, bei 'ner Ente ist das Eine und das Andere ja mehr oder weniger dasselbe...

Comment: Vielleicht liegt die Erklärung in der Tatsache, dass ihre Mutter Holländerin ist? Oder darin dass es eine HUMOR-Talkshow war? Ansonsten ist der Wortstamm für dieses Wort sehr sehr alt und in den meisten germanischen Sprachen vorhanden

Comment: https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesäss  http://www.koelsch-woerterbuch.de/po-auf-koelsch-453.html  https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Füdle

Comment: Der Schwabe/Alemanne sagt "Fiedle" fürs Gesäß. Zumindestens sprachlich ähnlich. Und er meint u.U. auch "Beides" damit.

Comment: @tofro und mit dem *Hennefiedle* kommt auch Federvieh ins Spiel

Comment: In Wuppertal versteht das jeder.

Comment: Latein *Podex* ist lautlich vergleichbar, nich?

Comment: @vectory Mit der Ausnahme, dass kein einziger Buchstabe und kein einziger Laut übereinstimmt, sind die zwei Worte schon sehr ähnlich.

Comment: @vectory: Welches deutsche Wort ist deiner Meinung nach mit *»podex«* (Lateinisch für Deutsch *»der Furzer«*) vergleichbar? *»Fut«* oder *»Gesäß«*? Erklär mir doch bitte mal, durch welche Lautverschiebung aus *»podex«* eines dieser Worte geworden sein soll.

Comment: @vectory: Doch, bitte erkläre das Grundwissen. Ich weiß nicht, warum *»po«* und *»fa«* verwandt sein sollen. Stammt *»fasten«* von *»posten«* ab? oder *»Faden«* von *»Poden«*? Ich glaube wohl eher nicht.

Comment: Weil ich zufällig wieder über \*potus etc. gestolpert bin und auch *anita* "Tante" entfernt an *Ente* erinnern mag, sei auch an diese Möglichkeit erinnert. Z. B ist altfriesisch *fethe* "father's sister" dahingehend ungeklärt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wie die von CarstenS gelinkten Seiten zeigen, bedeutet dieses Wort in der Tat *Gesäß*, *Po*. Die am meisten bekannte Schreibweise ist *Fott*, wie man es aus dem Kölschen kennt. Im Öcher Platt (Aachen) ist es hingegen *Futt*.

Hückelhoven liegt geographisch näher zu Aachen als Köln, der dortige Dialekt ist also sehr wahrscheinlich dem Öcher Platt näher. Da ich selbst aber aus einer anderen Richtung stimme, kann ich dies nur annehmen. Ich halte es aber für sehr plausibel.

Das Wort gehört ausschließlich zu meinem passiven Wortschatz (ich verstehe beide Dialekte, Kölsch und Öcher Platt, spreche aber keines aktiv), und interpretiere das Wort (insbesondere ohne Kontext) immer als *Gesäß*, *Po*. Dennoch ist mir auch die dir vertraute Bedeutung bekannt, die — zumindest meiner Auffassung nach — aber im Vergleich der beiden Bedeutungen recht hohen Seltenheitswert hat. Ich kann nicht mal mit Gewissheit sagen, ob *Futt* als Bezeichnung des weibl. Geschlechtsorgan überhaupt Bestandteil der ripuarischen Dialekte ist.

Auf jeden Fall bedeutet *Futt* bzw. *Fott* (und mögliche andere Abweichungen in anderen Dialekten, mir ist noch *Fött* bekannt oder insbesondere *Föttche* / *Föttchen*) in den ripuarischen Dialekten *Gesäß*, *Po*. Und ist natürlich nicht mit *fott* zu verwechseln, was *fort* bedeutet.

> Fott oder Föttche: Ja, es ist ein Körperteil. Nein, es ist nicht so etwas Unanständiges, wie Nicht-Rheinländer jetzt vielleicht denken. Die Fott ist auf Kölsch nichts anders als der Hintern, und wer im übertragenden Sinn "op es Föttche gefalle" ist, der wäre hochdeutsch ebenso bildlich auf die Schnauze gefallen. <sup>[QUELLE](https://books.google.de/books?id=qYYiBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&dq=f%C3%B6ttche&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWgJbR_MDQAhUDtRQKHQVhAVkQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=f%C3%B6ttche&f=false)</sup>

Comment: Auf Schwedisch haben wir das alte und jetzt nicht mehr gebrauchte Wort "Hundsfott", das angeblich aus dem Niederdeutschen oder Holländischen eingeleiht worden ist. Die Bedeutung ist aber genau dieselbe wie sie der OP sie beschreibt:  die äussere Geschlechtsorgane von einer Hündin, und wurde auch als grobes Schimpfwort verwendet. Ich finde dies komisch weil wir ja das Wort gerade von den nördlichen deutschen Sprachraum haben. Da müsste es sich historisch die Bedeutung in den Regionen zu denen Em1 referiert, verschoben haben.

Comment: @Beta https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundsfott_(Schimpfwort)

Comment: Und am Rande erwähnt gibt es noch das [Stippeföttche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stippeföttche).

Comment: Ich denke das Wort Fotze stammt auch daher.

Comment: Die Frage erinnert mich (aus Hessen) an meine Oma (aus Westfalen): Wir diskutierten mal über die Bedeutung von "Fut/Futt/Fott" (Schreibweise unklar). Sie sagte, das ist "hinten", ich sagte, das sei "vorne". In Westfalen kann also wohl tatsächlich "der Hintern" gemeint sein. Detlef Steves sagte in der vox-Serie _"Ab in die Ruine"_ im Hinblick auf eine Heizung im Dachboden einmal "Ich möchte meinen Dachboden ausbauen und da ne warme Fott haben". Klingt für mich ebenfalls nach "Hintern".

Comment: Und der Bayer sagt, wenn er unter sich ist, "halt die Fotzn" und meint damit, oh Wunder, "das Maul"

Comment: Im Ripuarischen müsste /ts/ vorherrschen und Verwechslung mit *Votze* ausgeschlossen sein. Allerdings bestünde ehemals Verwechslungsgefahr mit einem ähnlichen Wort, zu gothisch  (fōdr), d.h. wie Vagina etwa Scheide, also Schwertscheide, dem auf Hochdeutsch nunmehr Jackenfutter entsprechen dürfte. Ob ein derbes Schimpfwort überhaupt einen astreinen Stammbaum haben kann, sei dahingestellt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin gebürtiger Aachener und kenne "Futt" in der Tat als "Hinterteil". Bezüglich der "Entenfut" scheint mir aber noch etwas anderes wesentlich: In Aachen sagt man: "dee wackelt wie en Entenfutt". Ich erinnere mich, zumindest im Rheinland auch die hochdeutsche Variante "der wackelt wie ein Entenschwänzchen" gehört zu haben; weiter verbreitet scheint mir die Variante "wackeln wie ein Lämmerschwänzchen" zu sein. Das würde darauf hindeuten, daß Frau Winkens als Kind vielleicht etwas zur Hyperaktivität neigte. Jedenfalls war der Spitzname zärtlich gemeint, und hatte keine herabsetzende oder obszöne Konnotation.

Comment: Seit Donald Duck's "Aua mein Bürzel !" kenne ich das Fachwort für diesen markanten Teil der Ente. Und (reale) Enten _wackeln_ ja  wirklich ständig, v.a. mit ihrem Heckteil. Es ist kein wedeln mit den Schwanzfedern, genaugenommen. Es ist nicht obszön, stimmt, aber es hat eine andere Konnotation als Lämmerschwänzchen oder Espenlaub. Aachen, Entenhausen, Basel: "Äntefudi" macht Sinn (ich habe es aber noch nie gehört).

Comment: Warum heißt der Platz in Aachen dann "Henger Herrjotts Fott"?

Answer (score 2):

Ich komme aus Düsseldorf und für mich ist die Futt ganz klar der Hintern!

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne den Begriff des *Füdli* (bei uns innerfamiliär als *Pfüdli* ausgesprochen) für den Po/Schließmuskel.

Ich sehe bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ges%C3%A4%C3%9F), dass dies ein Begriff aus der Schweiz ist. Wie der in unsere nürnberger/hannoveraner Mischfamilie gekommen ist, kann ich nicht wirklich sagen.

Ich habe aber *Füdli* immer als Verkleinerungsform wahrgenommen. Somit könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass es einen *Fud*/*Fut*/*Futt* gibt, der zu dieser Verkleinerung geführt hat.

Aber das alles entspringt keinem Etymologiewörterbuch.

Comment: Ich habe Quellen gesehen, die sagen, dass das "li" ursprünglich keine Verkleinerungsform ist, sonder von "Loch" kommt.

Comment: Zu "Füdli", schweizerdeutsch "Hinterteil": Ich hatte mal einen Schweizer Chef, der Sprachwissenschaftler war, für den war "Füdli" eindeutig eine Diminutivform. Die Verbindung zu "Loch" scheint mir ausgeschlossen: Erstens von der Lautentwicklung her, und zweitens: was würde das denn für die vielen Schweizer bedeuten, die Bünzli, Bürkli, Füssli oder ähnlich heißen?

Comment: Das ist eine seltsame Form zwischen "Fudi" und "Füdeli". Es gibt auch das vergröbernde "Füdle".  Das Wort wächst gewissermassen mit dem Sprecher, und beide verändert sich.  Ausser  "uffs Füdle gheit" (auf den Hintern/A. gefallen, am besten i. ü. S.) ist das ein Kinderwort -  und Kinder wissen ja nicht den Unterschied zwischen links und rechts.

Comment: "Ich hatte mal einen Schweizer Chef..."  Also mich interessiert diese Anekdote. Erinnert mich an eine gewissen Schweijk, der ein tschechisches Wort eines anderen so _hübsch_ übersetzt hat: "Milatschek, das ist wie: Herr Feldwebel !"

Answer (score 1):

Ich interessiere mich für Historisches und Erotisches, also auch in Kombination. Und dabei stoße ich natürlich immer wieder mal auf kuriose Funde, bei denen mit dem Wort Fut eindeutig die Vulva gemeint ist. Ein konkretes Beispiel ist ein erotisches Lied aus dem im Jahre 1906 erschienenen Privatdruck "Erotische Volkslieder aus Deutsch-Österreich", von dem es eine moderne Reprint-Ausgabe mit dem Titel »Deftig und direkt« gibt.
￼

Hier der Liedtext aus dem Buch:

1. Mein Herr, lieben Sie etwas
   Von meiner Ware?
   Hier ist der Mund, hier ist die Brust,
   Hier ist die Fut samt Haare.
2. Befehlen Sie es an der Wand,
   Befehlen Sie es im Bette,
   Es ist doch aller Welt bekannt,
   Daß ich die beste hätte.
3. Zehn Gulden zahlt ein Offizier,
   Fünf Gulden ein Advokate,
   Einen Gulden zahlt ein Grenadier,
   Zehn Kreuzer der Soldate.
4. Die Handwerksburschen, die sind frei,
   Sie zahlen was sie wollen,
   Doch wehe dem, der mir die Fut zerreißt,
   Den soll der Teufel holen.
5. Und wenn sie ganz zerrissen ist,
   So bleiben noch die Haare,
   Und wenn man sie fücken lässt,
   So hält´s noch viele Jahre.

Hier ein Link zur Reprint-Ausgabe:
https://www.edition-wh.at/product/deftig-und-direkt/

Ich kenne das Wort aber auch von wie Comics gezeichneten Porno-Geschichten aus dem 19.Jh.

Was aber das Beste ist, auch in meiner Kindheit und Jugend im Süden Münchens, war das Wort Fut auf dem Pausenhof der Schule das gängige Wort für Vulva, und das in der Zeit zwischen 1970 und 1980. Woher das Wort kam, wusste ich damals noch nicht, aber es war im pubertären Alter wirklich ein alltägliches Wort.

Ich glaube aber nicht, dass das Wort Fut früher tatsächlich so sehr grob-abwertend gemeint war (wie oben beschrieben). Der Begriff ist veraltete Gossensprache, die wir heute so oder so auffassen können.

Answer (score 0):

Ich komme aus dem Münsterland aus der Nähe von Gronau, spreche selbst kein Platt. Ich weiss aber von meiner Mutter die Hochdeutsch als Fremdsprache lernen musste das Futt in vielen Fällen als sehr vulgäres Schimpfwort verwendet wurde. Die Bedeutung beinhaltete wohl beides gleichzeitig Hintern und Vagina.