# Setz dich auf deine vier Buchstaben – welche Buchstaben?

Tags: idiom

Die Redewendung "Setz dich auf deine vier Buchstaben" heißt, dass man seine Kehrseite auf eine feste Oberfläche platzieren soll (= sich hinsetzen soll). Im Englischen wäre es klar, was die 4 Buchstaben sind – butt, arse, etc.

Was sind aber die 4 Buchstaben auf Deutsch?

Po – 2

Arsch – 5

Hintern – 7

Kehrseite – 9

Allerwertester – viele

Gluteus Maximus – noch mehr

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ich kenne es aus meiner Kindergartenzeit, und da war der [*Popo*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Popo) gemeint, also die kindersprachliche Variante von *Podex*.

---

<sub>**Zur Etymologie (aus dem [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Popo)):**</sub>

<sub>**Podex** m. ‘Gesäß, Hintern’, Entlehnung (um 1600) von gleichbed. lat. *pōdex*, eigentlich ‘Furzer’, Substantivbildung zu lat. *pēdere* ‘furzen’. Zunächst wohl, vermittelt durch Lateinschulen, als euphemistischer Ausdruck in dt. Texten. Daraus verkürzt mit nachfolgender Verdoppelung **Popo** m. kindersprachlich (2. Hälfte 18. Jh.). Erneute euphemistische Kürzung ergibt **Po** (20. Jh.).</sub>

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sich_auf_seine_vier_Buchstaben_setzen) nennt als weiteren Erklärungsansatz, dass der Ausdruck auf die vier "Buchen staben", also die "Stäbe" oder Stuhlbeine aus Buchenholz zurückgehen könnte. Laut [redensarten-index.de](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~sich+auf+seine+vier+Buchstaben+setzen&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) gibt es in Süddeutschland auch die Fassung "sich auf seine _fünf_ Buchstaben setzen", was auf das deutlich derbere "Arsch" zurückgehen könnte. Diese Variante ist mir bisher allerdings noch nicht untergekommen.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, das mit den vier Buchenholzstäben ist interessant, denn dass *Buchstabe* von den Buchenstäben abgeleitet sei, habe ich woanders schonmal gelesen.

Comment: Spannend finde ich, dass "Po" eine "erneute euphemistische Kürzung" historisch gesehen ist. Für mich war das bereits völlig normal und kein Euphemismus ... das Original habe ich nie nachgelesen^^

Comment: @Shegit Brahm, kann ja wohl gut alt ererbt sein. siehe [Does the letter p in a word mean that the word is not Germanic?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36588/does-the-letter-p-in-a-word-mean-that-the-word-is-not-germanic/36593#36593)

Comment: Ich bitte um Entschuldigung, die Thematik veranlasste mich unwilkürlich zu derben Späßen. Allerdings sollte diese Tatsache meine Aussage doch bekräftigen, ja eigentlich ihr Grundgehalt werden. Derweil bleibt der tiefere Sinn zur Interpretation vorbehalten. Bin da sonst ganz vorbehaltlos: Das war keine Unterstellung und kein Irrglaube, sondern eine gut gemeinte Frage von mir auf andere schließend--was im Umkehrschluss dennoch die jeweilige Anmaßung zuließ. habe es gelöscht

Comment: Zu bemerken wären noch die regionalen Aussprachedifferenzen: [ˈpopo] oder [ˌpoˈpoː]. Letzteres wird zB. in Österreich ausschließlich gebraucht.

Comment: @phipsgabler, stimmt. Ich selbst, aus Nordostdeutschland, würde es [ˈpopo] aussprechen. Die andere Variante hat für mich einen französischen Anklang.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Richtig. Ich (Österreicher) kenne das Wort *Popo* nur mit Betonung auf der zweiten lang gesprochenen Silbe, so wie auch *Kaffee* in Österreich auf der zweiten (und ebenfalls lang gesprochenen) Silbe betont wird (also genau gleich wie *Café*). Die Betonung auf der ersten Silbe klingt für österreichische Ohren schlichtweg falsch (sowohl beim Popo als auch beim Kaffee). Meiner persönlichen Wahrnehmung nach wurde der einsilbigen *Po* ebenfalls aus Deutschland nach Österreich importiert, ist hier aber mittlerweile ungefähr ebenso häufig wie der zweisilbige und hinten betonte Popo.

Answer (score 0):

Im Ruhrgebiet wird der *Popo* auch als *Futt* bezeichnet.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33402/fut-gesäß-wo-im-deutschen-sprachraum In Österreich wären das aber 3 Buchstaben weil ”Fut“ hier mit einem T geschrieben wird.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Wäre es möglich, noch Kontext zu ergänzen - z.B., ob im Ruhrgebiet trotz "Futt" das Sprichwort in Hochdeutsch gebraucht wird? (und bitte als eigenständige Antwort ausfüllen, denn die Frage geht keineswegs von Popo als Lösung aus.